# SharpSSH .NET Library: unable to connect to Linux (Debian) from .NET

Tags: .net, linux, exception, debian, sharpssh

I'm trying to connect to Linux using SharpSSH, but am unable to.  I want to run some Linux commands from my .NET application.

**Install Instructions:**

SharpSsh - .NET library to connect to UNIX via SSH
- create account @ codeproject.com
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET (download demo project and binaries/dll files)
- copied into "SharpSsh" folder

I'm running the sharpSshTest console application that comes with this download.  When I manually SSH (port 22) to Linux via Putty for same host/login/password, I'm able to connect fine.  When connecting with the same host and credentials via .NET, I get an exception thrown in the Tamir.sharpSsh .NET library.

**Unix distribution and version:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.9 (lenny)
Release:        5.0.9
Codename:       lenny
```

**StackTrace:**

```
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect()
   at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshStream..ctor(String host, String username, String password)
   at sharpSshTest.sharpSshTest.SshStream() in C:\Source\{path}\selenium_references\sharpSsh_Demo\sharpSsh.demo\sharpSshTest.cs:line 76
```

**Line 76 in sharpSshTest.cs:**

```
SshStream ssh = new SshStream(host, user, pass);
```

**Value of e.Message:**

```
{"verify: False"}
```

**Here's the code if it helps:**

```
using System;
using Tamir.SharpSsh;
using System.Threading;

namespace sharpSshTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for sharpSshTest.
    /// </summary>
    public class sharpSshTest
    {
        static string host, user, pass;
        public static void Main()
        {
            PrintVersion();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1) Simple SSH session example using SshStream");
            Console.WriteLine("2) SCP example from local to remote");
            Console.WriteLine("3) SCP example from remote to local");
            Console.WriteLine();

            INPUT:
            int i=-1;
            Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
            try
            {
                i = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
                Console.WriteLine();                
            }
            catch
            {
                i=-1;
            }

            switch(i)
            {
                case 1:
                    SshStream();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Scp("to");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Scp("from");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write("Bad input, ");
                    goto INPUT;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get input from the user
        /// </summary>
        public static void GetInput()
        {
            Console.Write("Remote Host: ");
            host = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("User: ");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            pass = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Demonstrates the SshStream class
        /// </summary>
        public static void SshStream()
        {
            GetInput();

            try
            {           
                Console.Write("-Connecting...");
                SshStream ssh = new SshStream(host, user, pass);
                Console.WriteLine("OK ({0}/{1})",ssh.Cipher,ssh.Mac);
                Console.WriteLine("Server version={0}, Client version={1}", ssh.ServerVersion, ssh.ClientVersion);
                Console.WriteLine("-Use the 'exit' command to disconnect.");
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Sets the end of response character
                ssh.Prompt = "#";
                //Remove terminal emulation characters
                ssh.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;

                //Reads the initial response from the SSH stream
                Console.Write( ssh.ReadResponse() );

                //Send commands from the user
                while(true)
                {
                    string command = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (command.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
                        break;

                    //Write command to the SSH stream
                    ssh.Write( command );
                    //Read response from the SSH stream
                    Console.Write( ssh.ReadResponse() );
                }
                ssh.Close(); //Close the connection
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Demonstrates the Scp class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cmd">Either "to" or "from"</param>
        public static void Scp(string cmd)
        {
            GetInput();

            string local=null, remote=null;

            if(cmd.ToLower().Equals("to"))
            {
                Console.Write("Local file: ");
                local = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Remote file: ");
                remote = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if(cmd.ToLower().Equals("from"))
            {
                Console.Write("Remote file: ");
                remote = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Local file: ");
                local = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Scp scp = new Scp();
            scp.OnConnecting += new FileTansferEvent(scp_OnConnecting);
            scp.OnStart += new FileTansferEvent(scp_OnProgress);
            scp.OnEnd += new FileTansferEvent(scp_OnEnd);
            scp.OnProgress += new FileTansferEvent(scp_OnProgress);

            try
            {
                if(cmd.ToLower().Equals("to"))
                    scp.To(local, host, remote, user, pass);
                else if(cmd.ToLower().Equals("from"))
                    scp.From(host, remote, user, pass,local);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PrintVersion()
        {
            try
            {               
                System.Reflection.Assembly asm
                    = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Tamir.SharpSsh.SshStream));
                Console.WriteLine("sharpSsh v"+asm.GetName().Version);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sharpSsh v1.0");
            }
        }

        #region SCP Event Handlers

        static ConsoleProgressBar progressBar;

        private static void scp_OnConnecting(int transferredBytes, int totalBytes, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            progressBar = new ConsoleProgressBar();
            progressBar.Update(transferredBytes, totalBytes, message);
        }

        private static void scp_OnProgress(int transferredBytes, int totalBytes, string message)
        {
            progressBar.Update(transferredBytes, totalBytes, message);
        }

        private static void scp_OnEnd(int transferredBytes, int totalBytes, string message)
        {
            progressBar.Update(transferredBytes, totalBytes, message);
            progressBar=null;
        }

        #endregion SCP Event Handlers


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that project is no good.  Downloaded the new one here, which consists of the actual source code of the new "SharpSSH" class library project and a console application called "Examples" when you open the Visual Studio solution file.

http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx#news

When launching the "Examples" console application, it worked!

```
SharpSSH-1.1.1.13

JSch Smaples:
=============
1)      Shell.cs
2)      AES.cs
3)      UserAuthPublicKey.cs
4)      Sftp.cs
5)      KeyGen.cs
6)      KnownHosts.cs
7)      ChangePassphrase.cs
8)      PortForwardingL.cs
9)      PortForwardingR.cs
10)     StreamForwarding.cs
11)     Subsystem.cs
12)     ViaHTTP.cs

SharpSSH Smaples:
=================
13)     SSH Shell sample
14)     SSH Expect Sample
15)     SSH Exec Sample
16)     SSH File Transfer
17)     Exit

Please enter your choice: 13

Enter Remote Host: {type host here}
Enter Username: testjobs
Use publickey authentication? [Yes|No] :No
Enter Password: helloworld

Connecting...OK
Linux gmqa 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem #1 SMP Thu Apr 7 22:17:10 UTC 2011 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Mar  6 09:58:32 2012 from {machine name}
testjobs@gmqa:~$
```

Comment: Yeah, that project is quite a bit out of date. I've done some updating and taken a few patches at bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh but it's far from ideal. Might also check out SSH.net on CodePlex.

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate in Linux and commands without launching a console window (with this library)?  If not, what library can I use?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't see why not since it does all the communication with the remote server.

Comment: Can you give me an example of calling the touch {filename} command, or some Linux command of your choice?

Comment: (NOTE: I haven't tested this) -- SshExec ssh = new SshExec(host, user, pass);

            ssh.Connect();

            String result = ssh.RunCommand("touch /tmp/restart.txt");

Comment: made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672698/linux-command-doesnt-work-from-net-execution-when-using-sharpssh-library